# Highlight cells if text is contained in any sheet of workbook?

Tags: excel

I'm using a spreadsheet to generate a series of game server configurations and using formulas to generate the commands. The tiers are broken down into separate sheets with a formula to generate the configuration command for what I want to modify regarding that tier. However, one sheet is a master list of all ~375 entity IDs that I want to highlight if they are entered on any other sheet in the document to make sure I have everything covered.

Any suggestions on this? I've tried using Vlookup and Countif, but I keep getting errors or not everything is properly highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a master worksheet with a list of IDs you may use nested `IFERROR` function if other worksheets contain ID keys.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),MATCH(A2,Sheet3!A:A,0)),"No Match")
```

Something like this:

[image][image][image]

Comment: @pnuts exactly. I did not get it clearly. Do you where exactly on the spreadsheet the instruction would be saved? Or appears randomly with no specific pattern?

Comment: try =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,A2)=0,IF(COUNTIF(Sheet3!$1:$1048576,A2)=0,"No Match","Match"),"Match")